# Is MicroUSB powerful enough to charge MiniUSB devices?

Tags: usb, battery, power

I have a few MiniUSB devices, living in a very MicroUSB-dominated world. It would be much more convenient for me to leave a MicroUSB charger plugged in all the time, and just throw on an adapter when needed for MiniUSB, than it would to have both chargers taking up power strip/wall outlet space or to be constantly swapping the whole chargers/cables.

However, I'm not very familiar with the differences between the USB standards. Particularly, I'm concerned that MicroUSB devices may be standardized at such lower power levels that a MicroUSB charger might not have enough juice to feed a device designed for MiniUSB even with an adapter.

Assuming a proper adapter can be found, does the MicroUSB standard support enough power flow to power and charge devices designed for the MiniUSB standard? Or is there a substantial enough difference, in terms of things affecting device/battery health and lifetime, that I should just stick with the regular chargers with no adapters?

Answer (score 2):

As you say, it is only and adapter, the power comes from your usb port or your AC charger.

Be sure your devices support charging through usb and check that the microusb AC charger doesn't output more power than the one intended for your miniusb device and you'll not have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Particularly, I'm concerned that MicroUSB devices may be standardized
>   at such lower power levels that a MicroUSB charger might not have
>   enough juice to feed a device designed for MiniUSB even with an
>   adapter.

This is not true. Both MiniUSB and MicroUSB devices can be connected to the same charger. They are electrically compatible and only differ in their connector.

In fact I have both a A to Mini and A to Micro cable connected to a computer so that I can charge both types of devices. One could substitute a USB charger with several A ports and then connect A to any of the USB connectors cables.